# Is there a FOSS implementation for Discrete Global Grid System & Global Statistical Geospatial Framework?

Tags: coordinate-system, dggs

This 2019 document, "[GSGF Europe -Implementation guide for the Global Statistical Geospatial Framework in Europe](https://www.efgs.info/wp-content/uploads/geostat/3/GEOSTAT3_GSGF_EuropeanImplementationGuide_v1.0.pdf)" describes the harmonization of two standards:

1. [INSPIRE D2.8.I.2_v3.1](https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/INSPIRE_DataSpecification_GG_v3.1.pdf) of year 2014;
2. [OGC's DGGS](https://docs.opengeospatial.org/as/15-104r5/15-104r5.html), *"Topic 21: Discrete Global Grid Systems Abstract Specification"*, of year 2017.

**Is there an official or experimental  FOSS  implementing these harmonized requirements?**

---

**NOTES** on my personal interpretation. The 2019 document suggests that a solution is feasible. Checking Internet, seems that is possible to use FOSS solution (free and open-source software)  for it.  For example using  [DGGRID](https://github.com/sahrk/DGGRID) project... Or, for more a flexible Requirements 5, 7 and 8 of DGGS standard (the hierarchy of *equal area* tessellations), projects like  [S2-geometry](https://s2geometry.io/) and [H3 Uber](https://h3geo.org/#/documentation/overview/use-cases).

Comment: Good article about open DGGS and comparing area distortions, https://doi.org/10.1080/20964471.2022.2094926

Answer (score 4):

Not yet. However, I agree with your interpretation that several are close and one of the [OGC DGGS working group](https://www.ogc.org/projects/groups/dggsdwg) key activities is to establish a registry of DGGS implementations so this is likely to change.

[Bondaruk et al. 2020](https://doi.org/10.1139/geomat-2019-0015) evaluates ddgridR, H3, OpenEAGGR and S2 against the '17 OGC standard. They conclude H3 is the closest followed by S2, but they also suggest some ways the standard could be tweaked for an easier determination.

Matthew Purss and Robert Gibb gave an OGC webinar on on 6/4/2020 (recording forthcoming? [link](https://www.ogc.org/webinars)) where this question was raised as well. They indicated S2, H3 and OpenEAGGR are close but because they are designed to operate within themselves don't completely meet the requirements. The R binding to DGGRID was raised as 'an exception' due to the other modeling tools available in R. I didn't interpret that as a full endorsement of compliance, and if it is I don't see why that isn't adequate for the others given say their python bindings etc.